# File Opened With fopen($file, 'w') Is Not Writeable

Tags: php, file-permissions, fopen

Loading a text file into a form with ***fopen($file, 'w')*** but the file is not write-able and changes cannot be saved. Obviously a permissions issue but I do not want to change them to 777 for obvious security reasons. Is there a way to do it on the fly, then change it back after saving?

```
<?php $file = "$ServerRoot/text/test.txt";
// $ServerRoot is defined elsewhere and is to the root of the filesystem

// Retrieve the submitted changes and save to the file
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") :
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("Can't open file for writing.");
    fwrite($fh, $_POST['textfield']);
    fclose($fh);
    echo "Content saved.";
endif;

// FOR DIAGNOSTIC PURPOSES ONLY
$TestFile = (file_exists($file)) ? "The file exists\n" : "The file does <font color=\"red\">NOT</font> exist\n";
$TestFile .= (is_readable($file)) ? "The file is readable\n" : "The file is <font color=\"red\">NOT</font> readable\n";
$TestFile .= (is_writable($file)) ? "The file is writable\n" : "The file is <font color=\"red\">NOT</font> writable\n";
$TestFile = nl2br($TestFile);

// Read the textfile
$text = file_get_contents($file);?>

<div align="center">
<?=$TestFile;?>
    <form action="<?=$submitFormAction;?>" method="post">
        <div><input type="submit" value="Save File" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></div>
        <div><textarea name="textfield" rows="25" cols="85"><?=htmlspecialchars($text);?></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Save File" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The webserver user should be the owner of the files / directories in your server. That way you won't have to chmod files. If you are the server owner, you should make sure of this. If not, you should slap your server provider for not doing it! - Also, to answer your question: No, you can't chmod files with more rights from within PHP if PHP doesn't have the rights to write to the file in the first place.

Comment: This is, so far, only offline on my development system and the files should all be owned by the webserver. I'll check it.

Comment: Well if you are sure that the webserver user is the owner, chmodding to 755 should suffice

Comment: @icecub You were right, the files are owned by me, not by the webserver! It seems to me (now that I think of it) that when it was set up several years ago that was the only way I was able to move, copy or save files and open files to edit them using a desktop application. I'll try changing back. The live server shouldn't have that limitation but it's too early in the development to test it there as this form does not yet have any authentication on it.

Comment: I would highly recommend checking out [ISPConfig 3](https://www.ispconfig.org/). It's completely free and they have complete tutorials on how to setup an entire (test) server for yourself. It's a bit of work but once you've done it all, you'll have a very easily managable server for everything you need.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I’m not a newbie to this sort of thing but had forgotten about this system’s unorthodox configuration until you mentioned it. However, what I’m not sure how to do is to find what the owner should be but there may still be some folders that were not changed that will give me the clue I need.

Comment: Assuming its a Unix based server, you should probably just do `ln -l` in your root dir or the dir above that. It should list all files / folders and their owners. That should give you a clue. If you're using apache as the webserver, the owner is probably `www-data` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never chmod files to 777. Not even temporarily. It's a security risk and shouldn't be needed on a server that's been setup properly.

If PHP is unable to write to a file, it means the webserver is not the owner of the file or you've somehow revoked writing permissions from the owner as root / administrator. Verify the owner of the file in question. If you are using Apache as your webserver, the owner should probably be something like `www-data`. If it's not the correct owner, make sure to fix that issue by changing the owner.

Keep in mind that if you've setup apache to serve multiple domains, the owner(s) are probably quite different, like `client1`, `client2` etc.

After you've made sure the correct owner is set, chmodding the file to 755 should be sufficient.